# using a flex item as a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wanted to use flexbox with a column layout, but I wanted the top `n - 1` flex items to be pinned to the top and the `nth` flex item to be pinned to the bottom of the main flex container area.

I solved this by using the `nth` flex item to also be a new flexbox/flex container using `justify-content: flex-end`, but I couldn't find any examples that were doing this - so is this a correct/acceptable solution according to the standard and, if not, how would I otherwise go about this with flexbox?

Here's a quick example:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: Silver;
}
.flex-container-bottom {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-item {
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.flex-item-bottom {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-container-bottom">
    <div class="flex-item-bottom">flex item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) isn't very clear on this, but it states that "Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item." This seems to imply that if I put a flex container inside another flex container that the inner flex container would also implicitly become a flex item  for its containing flex container even if this is not explicitly defined. Example 1 of the specification shows a flex container within a flex container and assuming it is legal syntax it follows that my use case may also be legal, but the section with example 1 is marked as non-normative... (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻... At this point I'm just going to assume this is correct.

Comment: The spec is completely clear about this: it's allowed.

Comment: if you have a better answer feel free to post it and I'll be happy to accept it as the answer - I didn't have time to take a fine comb to the standard

Comment: It's not that I have a better answer, but I think the quote in your answer is clear enough. The Overview section is non-normative because it's just a summary of the following sections, which are the "real" spec.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say that your use of `flex-end` is wrong because you're getting the desired effect, but there's an easier way to do it.

Try using:

```
.flex-container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

`justify-content: space-between;` forces your flex items to spread out as much as possible in the flex container.

This is the reference guide I use whenever doing anything with flexboxes:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this this will make your last item to stick to bottom of your parent container

```
.flex-container{
    position:relative;
   }
 .flex-item-bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
 }
```