# Display flex within a flexed item

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get my link text here centered vertically and horizontally but for some reason it is left aligned. I thought the flex based alignments would have centered this? I have looked at [using a flex item as a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143181/using-a-flex-item-as-a-flex-container) and believe it is allowed but for some reason isn't working.

```css
.trow {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 350px;
}

img {
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

a {
  height: 58%;
  background-color: #3d7db7;
  width: 100%;
}

#box1 {
  flex: initial;
}

#box2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center; /* thanks to answers but vertically not working?*/
}
```

```html
  
  <div class="trow">
    <div id="box1"><img src="images/Image.png"></div>
    <div id="box2">
      <a href="#">Link here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your anchor is not the full height of it's container, you need to make it's container flex and add vertical alignment to that - that gets you the blue in the center of the parent div.

Next, to center the text in the anchor, you need to make that flex and align and justify the content for that too:

```css
.trow {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 350px;
}

#box2 {
  flex-grow: 1;         /* make link holder grow the rest of the width (and height) */
  display: flex;        /* add this to allow for vertical centring of it's content */
  align-items: center;  /* this vertically centres */
}

a {
  display: flex;             /* add this to allow for vertical and horizontal centring of the anchor text */
  justify-content: center;   /* horizontal centre */
  align-items: center;       /* vertical centre */
  height: 58%;
  background-color: #3d7db7;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="trow">
  <div id="box1"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div id="box2">
    <a href="#">Link here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To align the text at the center use: `text-align: center`

For the vertical alignment, add `flex` also to `a`

```css
.trow {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

a {
  height: 58%;
  background-color: #3d7db7;
  width: 100%;
}

#box1 {
  flex: initial;
}

#box2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#box2 a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="trow">
    <div id="box1"><img src="images/Image.png"></div>
    <div id="box2">
      <a href="#">Link here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue here though is not just the text align but the vertical align isn't correct either .... if the image is 100px high - it won't work :(

Comment: This now sits over the image?

Comment: What do you mean by sits? I set the img to 100x100 so will be more clear the result

Answer (score 0):

Added `text-align: center;` for #box2.

```css
.trow {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 350px;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

a {
  height: 58%;
  background-color: #3d7db7;
  width: 100%;
}

#box1 {
  flex: initial;
}

#box2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="trow">
  <div id="box1"><img src="images/Image.png"></div>
  <div id="box2">
    <a href="#">Link here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately if the image is 100px high it doesn't justify vertically either

Comment: Please check it now. I have set height 100px to the image and it is vertically centered.

Comment: I'm afraid I still see it top aligned and as per my updated question.

Comment: Unfortunately the height has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of change everywhere, check out the differences

```css
.trow {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 350px;
}

img {
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

a {
  background-color: #3d7db7;
}

#box2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="trow">
  <div id="box1"><img src="images/Image.png"></div>
  <div id="box2">
    <a href="#">Link here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```